# Vaadin: how to clear integer/number values in fields of a FormLayout?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

In my spring-boot vaadin app I have a component extending a FormLayout with some fields binded to an Entity.
To create a new object with the form first I create: new Entity() an then I set bean in the binder for it:
binder.setBean(new Entity as a param).
The first to fields are of type: IntegerField(for integer input) and NumberField(for double input). Those fields get filled with 0 - for integer and 0.0 for double. I would like to clear the values in those fields so they are ready to fill with fresh data.

How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
binder.getFields().forEach(f -> f.clear());
```

But I end up in NullPointerException on method: clear().
Debugger looks like this:
[image: debugger screen]

binder = 'this' is not available   is shown - what might be the solution?

Maybe there is a better way to celar the form fields???

The Log is below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.lambda$writeFieldValue$5169480d$1(Binder.java:1247) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.SimpleResult.handle(SimpleResult.java:77) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.ValidationResultWrap.handle(ValidationResultWrap.java:81) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Result.ifOk(Result.java:145) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.writeFieldValue(Binder.java:1247) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.access$1600(Binder.java:1032) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.lambda$doWriteIfValid$4(Binder.java:1955) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.doWriteIfValid(Binder.java:1954) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder.handleFieldValueChange(Binder.java:1560) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.handleFieldValueChange(Binder.java:1230) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder$BindingImpl.lambda$new$f9b94f89$1(Binder.java:1068) ~[flow-data-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.lambda$addValueChangeListener$828eca10$1(AbstractFieldSupport.java:96) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:194) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.Component.fireEvent(Component.java:359) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentUtil.fireEvent(ComponentUtil.java:386) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setValue(AbstractFieldSupport.java:207) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.internal.AbstractFieldSupport.setValue(AbstractFieldSupport.java:133) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.AbstractField.setValue(AbstractField.java:181) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.AbstractNumberField.setValue(AbstractNumberField.java:293) ~[vaadin-text-field-flow-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.AbstractNumberField.setValue(AbstractNumberField.java:38) ~[vaadin-text-field-flow-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.HasValue.clear(HasValue.java:179) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.jg.marketing.ui.views.list.NewReceiverForm.lambda$clearForm$0(NewReceiverForm.java:107) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497) ~[na:na]
    at com.jg.marketing.ui.views.list.NewReceiverForm.clearForm(NewReceiverForm.java:107) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.jg.marketing.ui.views.list.NewReceiverForm.lambda$createButtonsLayout$2f54d9f7$4(NewReceiverForm.java:101) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:205) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:373) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:264) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:441) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:59) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:64) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:409) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:390) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:390) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:317) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:89) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1545) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) ~[flow-server-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:111) ~[vaadin-spring-12.3.2.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.5.RELEASE.jar:5.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

The line 107 points to    clear()   method.

Below is my FormLayout where are the fields I would like to clear().

```
package com.jg.marketing.ui.views.list;

import com.jg.marketing.backend.entity.Receiver;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventListener;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Key;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.ButtonVariant;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.formlayout.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.Icon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.icon.VaadinIcon;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.IntegerField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.NumberField;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.validator.DoubleRangeValidator;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.validator.IntegerRangeValidator;
import com.vaadin.flow.shared.Registration;

public class NewReceiverForm extends FormLayout {

    IntegerField sapNumber = new IntegerField("SAP", "fill with a number");
    NumberField score = new NumberField("Realizacja %", "i.e.: 99.99 ");
    TextField type = new TextField("Segment", "fill with SEGMENT");
    TextField city = new TextField("Miasto", "fill city");
    TextField postCode = new TextField("Kod pocztowy", "i.e..: 12-345");
    TextField street = new TextField("Ulica", "fill street");
    TextField streetNumber = new TextField("Nr budynku", "np.: 125 B");
    TextField phoneNumber = new TextField("Nr kontaktowy", "phonenumber");


    Button save = new Button("Dodaj", new Icon(VaadinIcon.PLUS));
    Button delete = new Button("Usuń", new Icon(VaadinIcon.MINUS));
    Button close = new Button("Anuluj", new Icon(VaadinIcon.CLOSE));
    Button reset = new Button("Wyczyść", new Icon(VaadinIcon.ERASER));

    Binder<Receiver> binder = new Binder<>(Receiver.class);

    public NewReceiverForm() {
        addClassName("new-receiver-form");

        binder.forField(sapNumber)
                .asRequired("Fill with number: min. 70000000 - max.79999999")
                .withValidator(new IntegerRangeValidator("YOu entered a wrong number SAP! 70000000 - 79999999", 70000000, 79999999))
                .bind(Receiver::getSapNumber, Receiver::setSapNumber);
        binder.forField(score)
                .asRequired("Fill percentage i.e.: 99.99")
                .withValidator(new DoubleRangeValidator("min. 0 max. 100", 0.00, 100.00))
                .bind(Receiver::getScore, Receiver::setScore);
        binder.forField(type)
                .asRequired("fill segment")
                .bind(Receiver::getType, Receiver::setType);
        binder.forField(city)
                .asRequired("fill city")
                .bind(Receiver::getCity, Receiver::setCity);
        binder.forField(postCode)
                .asRequired("fill postcode")
                .bind(Receiver::getPostCode, Receiver::setPostCode);
        binder.forField(street)
                .asRequired("fill street")
                .bind(Receiver::getStreet, Receiver::setStreet);
        binder.forField(streetNumber)
                .asRequired("fill street number")
                .bind(Receiver::getStreetNumber, Receiver::setStreetNumber);
        binder.forField(phoneNumber)
                .asRequired("fill phonenumber")
                .bind(Receiver::getPhoneNumber, Receiver::setPhoneNumber);

        add(
                sapNumber
                , score
                , type
                , city
                , postCode
                , street
                , streetNumber
                , phoneNumber
                , createButtonsLayout()
        );

    }

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        binder.setBean(receiver);
    }

    private HorizontalLayout createButtonsLayout() {
        save.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        save.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
        save.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> validateAndSave());

        delete.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
        delete.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> fireEvent(new DeleteEvent(this, binder.getBean())));

        close.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);
        close.addClickShortcut(Key.ESCAPE);
        close.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> fireEvent(new CloseEvent(this)));

        binder.addStatusChangeListener(evt -> save.setEnabled(binder.isValid()));

        reset.addClickListener(buttonClickEvent -> clearForm());

        return new HorizontalLayout(save, delete, reset, close);
    }

    // Clear fields in form
    private void clearForm() {
        binder.getFields().forEach(f -> f.clear());
    }

    private void validateAndSave() {
        if (binder.isValid()) {
            fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, binder.getBean()));
        }
    }

    // Events
    public static abstract class NewReceiverFormEvent extends ComponentEvent<NewReceiverForm> {
        private Receiver receiver;

        protected NewReceiverFormEvent(NewReceiverForm source, Receiver receiver) {
            super(source, false);
            this.receiver = receiver;
        }

        public Receiver getReceiver() {
            return receiver;
        }
    }

    public static class SaveEvent extends NewReceiverFormEvent {
        SaveEvent(NewReceiverForm source, Receiver receiver) {
            super(source, receiver);
        }
    }

    public static class DeleteEvent extends NewReceiverFormEvent {
        DeleteEvent(NewReceiverForm source, Receiver contact) {
            super(source, contact);
        }

    }

    public static class CloseEvent extends NewReceiverFormEvent {
        CloseEvent(NewReceiverForm source) {
            super(source, null);
        }
    }

    public static class ResetEvent extends NewReceiverFormEvent {
        ResetEvent(NewReceiverForm source) {
            super(source, null);
        }
    }

    public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(Class<T> eventType,
                                                                  ComponentEventListener<T> listener) {
        return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
    }

}
```

Comment: Following your prose i can not reproduce this. Please provide the actual failing code or even better provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What are the types of the properties of the entity you bind?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli: integer for IntegerField; double for NumberField and String for TextField. The only way that I found to clear the form is to invoke clear() method on every field like:
```
public void clearForm() {
        this.name.clear();
        this.quantity.clear();
        this.width.clear();
        this.height.clear();
        this.material.clear();
        this.properties.clear();
    }
```
But there has to be a way to do it more elegant.

Comment: Is it Double or double and Integer or int?

Comment: integer for IntegerField; double for NumberField

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing the fields on the form, set the entity instancee properties to null. You can always set Integer, Big decimal etc properties to null.

Comment: That would propably do it @Vikrant Thakur. Can't do it with primitives though. They always have default values. What I was looking for was the way to clear the form for the user while not touching those binded values.